# Global config parameters using Servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, web.xml, properties-file

I'm developing a web app using JavaEE. My question is about which is the best practice to use global config parameters that I could use from every Servlet or JSP page.

I have this two possibilities:

**1. Using web.xml file and its context-param values**, like:

```html
<context-param>
   <param-name>myParam</param-name>
   <param-value>theValue</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and then retrieve the values in this way:

```
String data = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getInitParameter("myParam");
```

**2. Using a .properties file that would be read by a singleton class with static attributes**. The config file would be something like:

```
myParam=theValue
```

and the class:

```
public class Config {

   private final static String FILE_CONFIG = "/WEB-INF/config.properties";
   private static String myParam = null;
   // more properties

   // singleton constructor and init attributes

   public static String getMyParam() {
      return myParam;
   }
   // more getters
}
```

So I use it in this way:

```
String data = utils.Config.getMyParam();
```

All in all, which option do you think is the best practice to develop? The first, the second, maybe another one...?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question might read as an opinion-based question to some, but IMO, you're basically asking which is better: a mechanism that's provided for by the JavaEE standard, or a bunch of custom code that's outside that framework. It's a no-brainer: the context-param config is there because it's recommended. All that custom code you've described for #2 is just unnecessary

Comment: Thanks @kolossus for your answer. Maybe that's the point. Anyone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will agree with @kolossus. Though both the methods are acceptable, using **context-param values of web.xml** is more *preferable* for following reasons:

1. Though both methods can handle data almost equally efficiently, *web.xml* file is the preferred option when it comes to **complex data**.
2. When we talk of complex data, interpreting the same correctly should also be easy. *web.xml* allows you to have data in **hierarchical order** and if required, maintaining a **parent-child relationship**.

e.g: In **Vehicles**, we have **two-wheeler** and **four-wheeler**. In two-wheeler we again have **bikes** and **scooter**. In scooter we have Vespa. In bikes we again have **economy-bike** and **sportsbike**.

```
<vehicle>
   <two-wheeler>
      <scooter>Vespa</scooter>
      <bike>
          <eco-bike>Hero</eco-bike>
          <sportsbike>Ducati</sportsbike>
      </bike>
   </two-wheeler>
</vehicle>
```

Representing above data in *.properties file* might become a bit clumsy.

3. It is in *XML format*. Hence your content can be used *across different systems*. XML file comes with character-encoding which allows different systems to understand how to interpret this particular file.

   The same is not the case with *.properties file*. You will have to encode it    specifically for the target system. Again it comes with the risk of data corruption on the other end.

For all these reasons(& probably few more), using *web.xml file and its context-param values* is recommended.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You both helped me so much. Regards!